# java.lang.VerifyError when running desktop application

Tags: java, proguard, install4j, proguard-maven-plugin

I have a desktop application in Java, I am using Proguard for obfuscation, and Install4j.
I am able to run the jar file of the application using the argument "-noverify" which was recommended by others who had the same issue. But I cannot run the exe file (added "-noverify" to the arguments in Install4j).

Any ideas please? thanks!

[image]

Comment: What was the version of java that you built the jar, and what is the version of java that you are running this in ?

Comment: For both I am using AdoptOpenJDK jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot

Comment: sometime you run into this running older java code in newer JVM versions, `-noverify` is not secure and will be removed as an option soon https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/1291169_1.html, you should probably try to track down the  invalid bytecode to get your code to run without `-noverify`

Answer (score 1):

According to [Troubleshooting](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/troubleshooting/troubleshooting) section of the Proguard manual, the recommendations for `VerifyError` are:

- Check the Proguard bug database and if this is a new bug, submit a bug report.
- Try using the Proguard option [`-dontoptimize`](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage#dontoptimize)

---

Running a Java application with `-noverify` is an **insecure hack** ... but if you really need to resort to that you *should* be able to get Install4j to set JVM options in the generated launcher.

> A common requirement is the capability to adjust the VM parameters of launchers after the installation has been completed or to determine the VM parameters at installation time depending on the environment like the target platform or some user selection in the installer.
>
> For this purpose, a parameter file in the same directory as the executable is read and its contents are added to the list of fixed VM parameters. The name of this parameter file is the same as the executable file with the extension `.vmoptions`.

For more details; see [The definitive guide to install4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/install4j.pdf#install4j.concepts.vmParameters).